# Changing backgroundcolor depending on variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

With Flutter i want to change the backgroundcolor of my app whenever the value of "color" variable changes.

```
 String color = "white";

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
```

I don't know how to set color to backgroundColor proprety.

Answer (score 2):

```
class AppColor {
      static const RED = "RED";
      static const GREEN = "GREEN";
      static const BLUE = "BLUE";
      static const DEFAULT = "DEFAULT";
    
      static const _colorMap = {
        RED: Colors.red,
        GREEN: Colors.green,
        BLUE: Colors.blue,
        DEFAULT: Colors.teal,
      };
    
      const AppColor._();
    
      static getColorFor(String color) => _colorMap[color.toUpperCase()] ?? _colorMap[DEFAULT];
    }
    
    class SO extends StatelessWidget {
      var color = 'red';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: AppColor.getColorFor(color),
          appBar: AppBar(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To store your color value, you can use `Color` type data:

```
Color myColor = Colors.white;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: myColor,
```

After that, you can change the myColor property, and your `backgroundColor` will also be changed.

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: But i get the color value from a string. I don't know how to change myColor property with a string value.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do that directly. But, if the only way is from the string type data, then you can use if/else conditional. So for example, if the value of a string id "white", return "Colors.white". And so on.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much !

Comment: You might want to review the way you are capturing the color value, most inputs accept custom objects like ```Color``` as the return value