# Is there a way to convert a String into a Color without using a Getter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, I have buttons which have the names of colours. When the user presses the button, the name of the colour is recorded as a string and then passed to my result screen widget.
Temporarily, I'm using a getter which does this:

```
  Color get resultColor {
    Color faveColorTDT;
    
    if (faveColor == 'Black') {
      faveColorTDT = Colors.black;
    }
    else if (faveColor == 'Red') {
      faveColorTDT = Colors.red;
    }
    else if (faveColor == 'Brown') {
      faveColorTDT = Colors.brown;
    }
    else {
      faveColorTDT = Colors.blue;
    }

    return faveColorTDT;
  }
```

and then I use the getter in the Text widget like this:

```
style:
  TextStyle(color: resultColor)
```

However, this is pretty inefficient if the number of colours increases.
So is there a way to convert a String to a Color or use a string in the colour parameter?

Comment: Why store it as a `String` at all?

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835615)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350117/5522344

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible since color names are just abstract words to refer to the actual
hexadecimal code representation in digital. You won't get it, at least not without a solution longer than it needs to be.

You could take another an approach less painful tough. Put your colors(`Colors.black`, `Colors.blue`, etc.) to be sent by those buttons you said, so that when the buttons are pressed, they'll send the colors objects rather than the color strings. This way you avoid the conditionals.